# My Siri Custom Intent is not showing Siri Shortcuts App options?

Tags: shortcut, siri

My Siri Custom Intent is not showing Siri Shortcuts App options like embedded image, and not showing "Shortcuts from your apps" in Shortcuts app too. What's wrong?

Xcode: 10.3

Deployent target: iOS 11

Test on iPhone X

[image]